# Call in python return code status only

Tags: python

I have the following code in python:

```
i = call(["salt-cloud", "-m", fileName, "--assume-yes"])
print (i)
```

`i` is always 0, because the operation is finished.

The problem is that I want to get the output of this operation. In our case:

```
window:
    ----------
    Error:
        ----------
        Not Deployed:
            Failed to start Salt on host window
```

is the output of running `salt-cloud -m fileName --assume-yes`, and it is an indication that error raised in this process, and I want to know it.

How can I achieve it in Python?

Comment: you can use subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `check_output` and catch a `CalledProcessError` which will be raised for any non-zero exit status:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError    

try:
    out = check_call(["salt-cloud", "-m", fileName, "--assume-yes"]) 
    print(out)   
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.message)
```

If you are using python < 2.7 you will need `Popen`, `check_call` and `check_output` were added in python 2.7:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["salt-cloud", "-m", filename, "--assume-yes"],stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()

print( err if err else out)
```

Comment: But it returns 0, even if the process is failed (like in my example - window was not deployed, but code 0 was returned)

Comment: Then it is a normal exit status.   try check_output. Does it ever raise a non-zero exit status?

Comment: I try the following:
`        try:
            from subprocess import check_output
        except Exception as e:
            print e`
and it gives me the following error:`cannot import name check_output`

Comment: are you using python2.6?

Comment: then use the second part of the answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `subprocess.call`, you might want to take a look at [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), which returns the output of the subprocess as a byte string.

Comment: Should I use it this way: 
`import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["salt-cloud", "-m", fileName, "--assume-yes"])`

Comment: You'll have to get the output in a variable if you want to use it. `output = subprocess.check_output(...)`

Comment: I try the following: ` try: from subprocess import check_output except Exception as e: print e` and it gives me the following error:cannot import name check_output